# Establish TCP connection to computer on different network without the recipient having to go into their router settings?

Tags: rust, tcp, port

#### Overview

I'm trying to establish a connection between two computers on different networks without requiring the recipient to have to mess with their router's port forwarding settings

#### Scenario

I'm currently using a Rust script to establish a tcp connection between 2 ports on the same computer and all that it is supposed to do is print `Hello, world!` to the terminal running `recipient.exe`. It works perfectly.

#### Question

Say I distribute this application to a bunch of users. Each user would have both recipient.exe and sender.exe, and would run either depending on if they wanted to send or receive information to/from another user.

**How do I let one user connect to the other without having to make them open their router settings?**

Is there a different protocol I can use? Is there a universally-open port I can use? Can the machine running the program force the router to open a port temporarily?

I've wondered this for a while and I finally ran into actually needing to solve it

#### recipient.rs

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::net::TcpListener;
use std::io::{Error, Read, Write};

fn main() {
    let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:7878").unwrap();

    for stream in listener.incoming() {
        let stream = stream.unwrap();

        println!("Connection established!");

        handler(stream).unwrap_or_else(|error| eprintln!("{:?}", error));
    }
}

fn handler(mut stream: TcpStream) -> Result<(), Error> {
    println!("Connection from {}", stream.peer_addr()?);
    let mut buffer = [0; 128];
    loop {
        let nbytes = stream.read(&mut buffer)?;
        if nbytes == 0 {
            return Ok(());
        }

        print!("Received data: ");

        for i in 0..nbytes {
            print!("{}", buffer[i] as char);
        }
        println!("");

        stream.flush()?;
    }
}
```

#### sender.rs

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::net::TcpStream;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:7878")?;

    stream.write(&"Hello, world!".as_bytes())?;
    stream.read(&mut [0; 128])?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This can be done by opening a *reverse tunnel*. This means that you must maintain some central server (kind of service registry) that is accessible from all your computers. Then each client should announce itself on that registry and maintain an open connection in order to be able to receive data.

Comment: Try googling "NAT traversal" and "STUN".

Comment: I also found some stuff on UDP hole punching which sounds promising. The concept of a low-power matchmaking server makes a lot of sense for me